# how to include requirements when using python bdist_rpm

Tags: python, python-3.6, rpmbuild

I am building a project. [CVE-bin-Tool](https://github.com/intel/cve-bin-tool) and want to create an RPM using the command

```
python3 setup.py bdist_rpm
```

The problem is that the rpm is successfully created but without any of the requirements being added in the rpm. When I install the RPM on another host where I did not manually install the requirements the packaged cve-bin-tool does not function.

Comment: Because the Python requirements are distribution dependant (the name of the package can slightly change) and so their installation I think is mandate to the final user/sysadmin. You can use a configuration management framework like ansible or saltstack to address this problem.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/fedora-python/pyp2rpm instead of bdist_rpm. That said it's not a silver bullet, you still need to check and tweak the resulting specfile.